# Inverse element in semidirect product

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

If K and Q are both groups and $h:Q\rightarrow \text{Aut}(K) $ is a homomorphism then the group operation for the semidirect product $K\rtimes_hQ$ is: $$(k_1,q_1)*(k_2,q_2)=(k_1h(q_1)(k_2),q_1q_2)$$

I am trying to prove that the inverse of $(k_1,q_1)\in K\rtimes_hQ $ is $(h(q_1^{-1})(k_1^{-1}),q_1^{-1})$.

I was able to prove it this way: $(k_1,q_1)*(h(q_1^{-1})(k_1^{-1}),q_1^{-1})=(1,1)$.

But I am having trouble proving it the opposite way:

$\begin{align}(h(q_1^{-1})(k_1^{-1}),q_1^{-1})*(k_1,q_1)&=(h(q_1^{-1})(k_1^{-1})h(q_1^{-1})(k_1),q_1^{-1}q_1)\\&=(h(q_1^{-1})(k_1^{-1})h(q_1^{-1})(k_1),1)\end{align}$

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Hint : use the fact that $h(q_1^{-1})$ is a automorphism of $K$.

Comment: Sigh, can't believe I didn't see that.Thank you,

Comment: @ArnaudD could you elaborate on your suggestion about the automorphism? I'm afraid I am just not seeing it.

Comment: Use the fact that $h(q_1^{-1})$ is a homomorphism. For ease i will denote $h(q_1^{-1})\equiv h_{q_1^{-1}}$, then from the last line
$$\big( h_{q_1^{-1}}(k_1^{-1})h_{q_1^{-1}}(k_1),1\big)=\big(h_{q_1^{-1}}(k_1^{-1}k_1),1\big)=\big(h_{q_1^{-1}}(1),1\big)=(1,1)$$